# can`t access laravel Query Builder result from view

Tags: php, laravel-5

I can`t access the values from this variable $post from controller:

in blade view:

```
@foreach($post as $p)
          <div class="col-md-3">
                 <div class="boxpromo">
                    <h4>{{ $p->title }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ $p->post_description }}</p>
                    <div class="price">
                        <div class="data">{{ $p->out_date }}</div>
                   <div class="cost">{{ $p->price }}</div>
                 </div>
               </div>
           </div>
  @endforeach
```

In controller i have:

```
public function postSearchTransport(Request $request, Post $post){
...
// create a new query builder
        $post = $post->newQuery();

        // add some filters from the user in the search query
        if($request->has('searchWord')){
            $post->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->input('searchWord').'%');
        }
...//more filters
$post->paginate(5);
return view('searchVehicle.showSearchPost')->with('post', $post);
}
```

What i did wrong? I should be able to access in the view all the values from the query result, but i can`t this way.

Should i convert that $post std object from controller into an array then return it to the view???

Comment: If you do `dump($p)` in your view, do you see the expected results (the correct objects that contain your required details in `$attributes` property?

Comment: i don`t see nothing. Nothing happens!

Comment: Did you encapsulate your `dump($p)` in curly braces `{{ dump($p) }}`? Need more than "nothing happens" to work with to be able to help! :)

Comment: yes i did. Nothing happes. I did in controller dd($post) and get https://kopy.io/iFTrb but if using dd($post->paginate(5)) i get this https://kopy.io/uP1js

Comment: "Nothing" cannot happen, as even if the variable was `null`, you would see `null` output on the screen. Are you sure your view is loading correctly? If you put any content outside the `@foreach` block, you should be able to see it. Perhaps you're editing/loading the wrong template file?

Comment: Try `dump($post)` istead to see if posts exists or not !!

Comment: dump($post) in view works. I get this like i said up https://kopy.io/iFTrb a bunch of stuff......but i don`t see the result

Comment: @Giedrius i am editing the corect view. The same result i get from $post varialbe in the view and controller.

Comment: Can you confirm which screenshot applied to the `dump` output you get in your view? As you should be getting a `LengthAwarePaginator` in your view, not a `Builder` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass to the view the returned value of `paginate` method like this :

```
$posts = $post->paginate(5);
return view('searchVehicle.showSearchPost')->with('post', $posts);
```

Comment: saving the $post->paginate(5) in a variable then return that variable to the view works. Why did not work like i did? returning only the $post?

Comment: now i have another problem....the pagination not working. Using  {{ $posts->links() }} and when change on the next page i get an error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251)
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 238)......

Comment: using get not post and {{ $posts->appends(request()->input())->links() }} solve the issue :)